# Using DataTables to a table with content from ajax

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, datatables, web-deployment-project

I am working on this program. The program displays the topics under a specific subject.

**My main question is, will the DataTable work in this kind of setup?**

This is the code in HTML.

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="subject_container">
                <table id="tbl_subject" class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Chapter</th>
                            <th>Topic</th>
                            <th>Content</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="disp_topics"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

This is the code snippet in jquery:

```
$(function(){
  //this is only for simplification. Subjectid will be coming from a select input.
  let subjectid = 1;
  get_topics(subjectid);

  //this part right here. If this cannot work, is there a way to make it work?
  $('#tbl_subject).DataTable();
});

function get_topics(subjectid){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'includes/subject_handler.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      key: 'get_topics',
      subjectid: subjectid
    },
    success: function(data){
      $('#disp_topics).html(data);
    }
  });
```

This is the code of includes/subject_handler.php:
I am using keys since there are other tasks handled by this same script file. Thank you for understanding.

```
if($_POST['key'] == 'get_topics'){
   $subjectid = $_POST['subjectid'];
   $data = '';

   if(!empty($subjectid)){
      $sql = "SELECT topic.subjectid, chapter, topic, content FROM topic INNER JOIN subject
             ON subject.subjectid=topic.subjectid WHERE topic.subjectid = ?";
      $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindValue(1, $subjectid);
      $stmt->execute();

      if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
         $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

         foreach($rows as $row){
            $data .= '<tr>
                        <td>'.$row['chapter'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['topic'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['content'].'</td>
                     </tr>';
         }

         exit($data);
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ajax](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax) attribute of data table.

```
$('#tbl_subject').DataTable( {
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    serverMethod: 'post',
    ajax: 'includes/subject_handler.php'
    columns: [
            {data: 'chapter', name: 'chapter'},
            {data: 'topic', name: 'topic'},
            {data: 'content', name: 'content'},
    ]
} );
```

And for backend if you need to access search value you can do like this,

```
$requestData = $_REQUEST;
$requestData['search']['value']
```

In your case this is how to use it in **where** close.

```
$sql .= " AND ( chapter LIKE '" . $requestData['search']['value'] . "%' ";
$sql .= " OR topic LIKE '" . $requestData['search']['value'] . "%' ";
$sql .= " OR content LIKE '" . $requestData['search']['value'] . "%' )";
```

And if you need to get sorting data you can get like this,

```
$requestData['order'][0]['column'] // column name which user sorts
$requestData['order'][0]['dir'] // derection (ASC/DESC)
```

In your case it will be like this and remember to use `$requestData['start']` and `$requestData['length']` for pagination to work.

```
$sql .= " ORDER BY " . $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']] . "   " . $requestData['order'][0]['dir'] . "   LIMIT " . $requestData['start'] . " ," . $requestData['length'] . "   ";
```

You can include this search value and order values inside your sql query inside backend.

And finally you need format the data before send to front end.

```
    $json_data = array(
        "draw" => intval($requestData['draw']),   // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw.
        "recordsTotal" => intval($totalData),  // total number of records
        "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
        "data" => $data   // total data array
    );
    echo json_encode($json_data);
```

This is much simpler than looks. Need to get total records count from query, and total filtered record count from another query and dataset in json.

I have added previous sql example only to explain. **For preventing SQL injection** you have to use **Prepared Statements**.

```
$sql .= " AND ( chapter LIKE ? OR topic LIKE ? OR content LIKE ?";
$params = array($requestData['search']['value'] . "%", $requestData['search']['value'] . "%", $requestData['search']['value'] . "%");
$stmt = $handle->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

And you need to do the same for **ORDER BY** and **LIMIT** part of the query.

and inside this [tutorial](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side) there is a nice example how it works on backend.

You can send data to back end also like this.

```
       ajax: {
            url: "Your url",
            data: function (d) {
                d.var1= 'var 1';
                d.var2= 'var 2';
            }
        },
```

And access the data in back end like this.

```
$var1 = $_REQUEST['var1'];
$var2 = $_REQUEST['var2'];
```

And be careful not to use **start and end** (E.g.:- `d.start= 'var 1';`) to pass data to back end since they are used for pagination. This [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/yajra-datatables-date-range-filter) has a nice example on this.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time and giving much effort to answering my question. Is it possible for me to send data to the server as well? I need to send the specific subject id along with the ajax request. I can't seem to find a specific example where I can do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think you can send it with url E.g.:- `includes/subject_handler.php?subject_id=1`. But easier to use the search input in datatable

Comment: @sjamilbahar Try this and add if you find something new. And belive me this is way better than mixing jquery ajax and datatable.

Comment: I have added a note on that. Thanks so much for improve :)